# Exporting a pandas df into an excel file that has formatting already in it?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've spent hours researching this issue but cant seem to find an answer. I have a template in Excel that has conditional formatting already applied to it. I want to import a pandas df into this already formatted excel file so that the data is being formatted accordingly (color, number format, etc.). Does anyone if this is doable? And if so, how?

Ive considered writing a macro and just importing it into python and applying to the df. Just want to see if there's an easier way that I haven't thought of/found. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to try openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook(excelpath) # load excel with formats
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(excelpath, engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, "Sheet1", columns=['a', 'b'], index=False) # only columns 'a' and 'b' will be populated 

writer.save()
```

Comment: this does not work as I had tried this previously. it just writes it to a new sheet, not to an already existing sheet unfortunately :(

Comment: Did you specify the sheet name?

Comment: yes. it just makes a new sheet with the same name but a [2] next to it

Comment: Well, the scripts works fine for me. keeping all formats (colors+formula) of columns that the script doesn't override. How many columns does your excel have? Are they similar to columns in your dataframe? They have to be identical!

Comment: ahh interesting. yeah I think that might be the issue! not the same column names. Thank you!!

Comment: If the answer worked, you are supposed to approve it! thanks

Comment: i did upvote it. It recorded your answer as satisfactory. Because i just created this account it isnt showing up publicly as i dont have enough reputation points.